# Accessing all Text in HTML from songmeanings.com

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the user comments from the HTML from this link using BeautifulSoup:

> http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107858560012/

However, the HTML Doc only displays the user comments from the first page of comments when using this code:

```js
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107858560012/"
response = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor).open(url)
html_doc = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

comments = soup.find_all('div', class_='text')
for c in comments:
    c.get_text()
    print c.prettify()
```

The problem is that the HTML document from that page does not include the rest of the comments past page 1 of comments. Clicking through pages 2, 3, 4 etc does not reload the page or change the HTML source code. How can I access the comments on all the pages past the first?

To Clarify: I meant the user written comments at the bottom of the web page, which can be found from the tag: div class="text". Those are the texts I want to extract, but only the first 10 user written comments are displayed in the HTML, when there are in reality 107 comments.

Comment: You should post your specific code with the specific problems you've encountered.

Comment: Try using selenium.

Comment: Apologies, but I did not think code was necessary because the code is not the issue here. The problem is that the HTML from that website only includes the comments from page 1. Clicking through pages 2, 3, 4 etc does not reload the page or change the HTML source code, which is where my problem is. However, I've included the code that I used just in case it helps.

Comment: @OtisCheng I don't know why you keep saying that it's not in the HTML source code... it is in the source code. Look for this tag: <div class="holder lyric-box"> `view-source:http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107858560012/`

Comment: Maybe I'm being unclear. I meant the user written comments at the bottom of the web page, which can be found from the tag: <div class="text">. Those are the texts I want to extract, but only the first 10 user written comments are displayed in the HTML, when there are in reality 107 comments.

Comment: @pvg I've updated the post to be more clear.

Comment: You need to manipulate the url by adding #comments although I can't work out how to specify a page, they're in the format name=page-1 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly what you are trying to do. 
But as far as I understand you are trying to get all the comments under a certain song. 
The problem in this case is that songmeanings.com is using an sort of Ajax call to there own API or service to get the rest of the comments. 
That is the reason why you aren't getting all of the comment.

What you could try is inspect what kind of calls they are doing to get the next row of comments and use that to get new comments.

Also if it is an option try to contact them to get maybe some API they have for the public.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thanks! I would have liked to be able to access the rest of the comments, but the 10 will have to do.